# MySQL linked table get the last row insered with table.value = X

Tags: mysql, sql

I current have a table project(id) and a table project_step (id, project,step(integer)).

1 project is linked to 1 or many project_step.

I want to get a list of project where the last entered project_step (project_step.id DESC) has a step = X.

I need to do this in a sub query but i don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return all column from both tables. The purpose of the extra subquery is to separately get the latest `ID` for every `project` on table `project_step`.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    project a
        INNER JOIN project_step b
            ON a.ID = b.project
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  project, MAX(ID) ID
            FROM    project_step
            GROUP   BY project
        ) c ON b.project = c.project AND
                b.ID = c.ID
WHERE   b.step = ?
```

Comment: I am giving a try at this right now, thank you. I need 10/15 minutes because this query is a bit more complex than this ;)

Comment: and... it's doing the job thank you so much JW (it was a bit over my SQL skills)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT project.* from project_step
JOIN project ON project.id = project_step.project 
GROUP BY project
HAVING SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(step ORDER BY step DESC SEPARATOR ' '), ' ', 1) = X
```